# Searching in SOLR fields that dont exist

Tags: solr

So I have Users who have some fields like [Field A] and [ Field B]. Fields can be empty or can not exists (user wont add there nothing).

Now my query is like that:

**Field A:Green**

Solr give me 100users who have green field.

I want to filter from this 100 users with some boosting

**FieldA: Green AND
(FieldB:Blue OR FieldB:*)**

Not it will give me all fields with Blue or all fields which have something in this fields. But i want people who don't have this field too.

I try:

**FieldA: Green AND
(FieldB:Blue OR FieldB:* OR (-FieldB:*))**

but it doesn't work

Comment: So you want every document that has _something_ or _nothing_ in FieldB? Why are you even querying `FieldB`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want to have in this que something or nothing. I want just have exactly same results as i filter by FieldA. fields B is only for sort them

Comment: So why are you filtering by FieldB? Just leave it out.

Comment: I dont want to miss that. For example: I have two fields Name and Surname. Now i want to filter people with Names and Surnames this query dont give me people with Names but without surnames

Comment: But `FieldA:Green AND (.. anything or nothing in FieldB)` is the same as just `FieldA:Green`. You have to expand your question and explain why this is a different case and why it doesn't solve what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try saving a fixed value for *empty* field.

So you could have:
FieldA: Blue
FieldB: 0

Then simply query
FieldA: Green AND (FieldB:Blue OR FieldB:0)

You could also switch your FieldB:* to FieldB:[* TO *]

Answer (score 1):

Ok maybe i will explain my problem again:

I have two fields: Name and Surname. I have 10 records with name:BOB and 3 records with surname: SMITH

First i filter:

name:BOB and query give me 10 records.

Now i want to filter all people who are Bob Smith and THEN i want to have people with name bob (Name BOB is obligatory) then i want people who have something else in fields Surname.

so my query looks like this:

name:BOB AND (surname:SMITH^3 or surname:*^0) - This give me people which name must be bob and on first people with surname smith, then people with other values. But "surname:*" dont give me people with empty field. So i try doing (-surname:*^0) but it didnt work.

Now people who have ONLY name BOB but dont have anything in surname are disabled from results